# Centering text in php image

Tags: php, image, php-gd

I'm not sure how I can center text in a php-created image using imagettftext. Here's my code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(260, 180);
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 60, 153, 181);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 200, $white);
$text = $_GET['tname'];
$font = 'OpenSans-Semibold.ttf';
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $x+1, $y+1, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: use [imagetttfbbox](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) to caculate how big your text is, then use that calculate where in the image the box should go.

Comment: Can you provide me with examples? I tried reading the documentation but I didn't really understand the part about the returned results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example, based on [imagetttfbbox](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php):

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 75);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// text, font and size to draw
$text = 'hello world';
$font = 'OpenSans-Semibold.ttf';
$size = 30;

// determine the size of the text so we can center it
$box = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);
$text_width = abs($box[2]) - abs($box[0]);
$text_height = abs($box[5]) - abs($box[3]);
$image_width = imagesx($im);
$image_height = imagesy($im);
$x = ($image_width - $text_width) / 2;
$y = ($image_height + $text_height) / 2;

// add text
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, $x, $y, $white, $font, $text);

// set content type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// output and destroy image
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late reply.